# Create an img with a link thats generated from an API

Tags: javascript, dom-events, handlebars.js

```
fetch("/api/jobs/", options)
   .then((response) => response.json())
   .then((response) => {
     console.log(response);
     for (let i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
       var jobTitle = document.createElement("h2");
       var jobDescription = document.createElement("a");
```

trying to create the image her and use the generated link from job_url to make an img that when clicked leads to that link

```
        var jobImage = document.createElement("img");
        jobImage.setAttribute(
          "src",
          "https://play-lh.googleusercontent.com/kMofEFLjobZy_bCuaiDogzBcUT-dz3BBbOrIEjJ-hqOabjK8ieuevGe6wlTD15QzOqw"
        );
        jobTitle.textContent = response[i].job_title;
        jobDescription.textContent = response[i].job_url;
        div.appendChild(jobTitle);
        div.appendChild(jobDescription);
      }
    })
    .catch((err) => console.error(err));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Place the `img` inside the `a`. The image should get the `src` and the `a` should get the `href`. This is very cumbersome, you should use some sort of template for this kind of tasks. Template is just a string representing the required html.

```js
var div = document.querySelector("div");
var response = [{
    job_title: "gardner",
    job_url: "https://example.com"
  },
  {
    job_title: "sailor",
    job_url: "https://stackoverflow.com"
  },
];

for (let i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {


  var jobTitle = document.createElement("h2");
  var jobDescription = document.createElement("p");
  var jobImage = document.createElement("img");
  var jobLink = document.createElement("a");
  jobImage.setAttribute(
    "src",
    "https://play-lh.googleusercontent.com/kMofEFLjobZy_bCuaiDogzBcUT-dz3BBbOrIEjJ-hqOabjK8ieuevGe6wlTD15QzOqw"
  );
  jobImage.style.width = "50px";
  jobLink.setAttribute("href", response[i].job_url);
  jobLink.appendChild(jobImage);
  jobTitle.textContent = response[i].job_title;
  jobDescription.textContent = response[i].job_url;
  div.appendChild(jobLink);
  div.appendChild(jobTitle);
  div.appendChild(jobDescription);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

EDIT: Now same effect, using some sort of template.

```js
var div = document.querySelector("div");
var template = document.querySelector("#my-template").innerHTML;

var response = [{
    job_title: "gardner",
    job_url: "https://example.com"
  },
  {
    job_title: "sailor",
    job_url: "https://stackoverflow.com"
  },
];



for (let i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {

  var card_html = template;
  card_html = card_html.replace('{href2}', response[i].job_url)
  card_html = card_html.replace('{href}', response[i].job_url)
  card_html = card_html.replace('{title}', response[i].job_title)
  card_html = card_html.replace('data-src', 'src')
  
  var card = document.createElement("div");
  card.innerHTML = card_html;
  div.appendChild(card)

}
```

```html
<div></div>

<div id="my-template" style="display:none">
  <div class="card">
    <a href="{href}">
      <img data-src="https://play-lh.googleusercontent.com/kMofEFLjobZy_bCuaiDogzBcUT-dz3BBbOrIEjJ-hqOabjK8ieuevGe6wlTD15QzOqw" style="width:50px">
    </a>
    <h2>{title}</h2>
    <p>{href2}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you! sorry im new to Javascript but what do you mean template?

Comment: So the difference is shorter syntax?

Comment: It's just easier to work with the HTML of the template if you want to make changes in the design.